# mup deploy works but image won't start

Tags: meteor, docker, npm, mup

I'm deploying my Meteor app with mup from a Windows 10 box to a Digital Ocean VPS. Latest version of mup, latest version of meteor, app runs fine on Windows and the app deployed and ran fine before adding node-uber NPM. I see the following error in the logs when the app tries to start:

`npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/node-uber/node_modules/sshpk/bin\sshpk-conv'`

Obviously the problem is with the backslash in the filename, but not sure where that is coming from or how to fix it. It isn't referenced in the package.json for node-uber. I've tried editting the package.json for sshpk on the Windows side, but that doesn't make any difference. I can't edit the file in the Docker container because the container keeps restarting and kicking me out.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this, perferably permanently so I don't have to jump through hoops every time I deploy?

Answer (score 0):

Actually manually editting the package.json file does solve the problem. Turns out I have multiple copies of sshpk installed because the parent NPMs are specifying specific versions as being required.

So the "fix" for this problem is the edit the "bin" section of the sshpk package.json file to flip the "\" to "/", save and rerun mup deploy.

Sigh...